# cx_Oracle persistent connection

Tags: python, transactions, pool, cx-oracle, persistent

I have a task to create persistent connection for two process with cx_Oracle.

It is need to execute some requests from first process and late some requests from second process in same transaction.

When try to use DRCP as described in

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/python-091105.html

with next code:

```
#coding: utf-8

import cx_Oracle

con1 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test', purity=cx_Oracle.ATTR_PURITY_NEW)
cur = con1.cursor()
cur.execute('''insert into gui_view (id, name, view_type, title) values (gui_view_s.nextVal, 'TEST_VIEW', 'grid', 'VIEW_TITLE') ''')
cur1 = con1.cursor()
cur1.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all1 = cur1.fetchall()
assert len(rows_all1) > 0, 'Not Exists!'
con1.close()

con2 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test1', purity=cx_Oracle.ATTR_PURITY_SELF)
cur2 = con2.cursor()
cur2.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all = cur2.fetchall()
assert len(rows_all) == 0, 'Exist!'

con3 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test')
cur3 = con3.cursor()
cur3.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all3 = cur3.fetchall()
con3.close()

assert len(rows_all3) > 0, 'Not Exists!'
```

But third assert is incorrect.
May be i use incorrect parameters ?

Connection Pool can be created by separate process that will store connection and communicate with other process by socket (probably as in sqlrelay).  may May be such tool also exists, but i can't find it. (Required that it should be small simple and open). Do you know some of them ?

With help of @Dmitry and http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_packages_dbms_xa.htm was created working example with using dbms_xa:

```
    #coding: utf-8

import cx_Oracle

req_start = '''
declare
  v_my_transaction  pls_integer;
  v_xa_xid     dbms_xa_xid := dbms_xa_xid(3322);
  v_xa_exception exception;
  v_ora_error pls_integer;
begin

  v_my_transaction  := dbms_xa.xa_start(
                        xid => v_xa_xid,
                        flag =>  dbms_xa.tmnoflags);

--Check if XA transaction is OK
  if v_my_transaction <> dbms_xa.xa_ok then
    v_ora_error := dbms_xa.xa_getlastoer();
    rabus_utl.debug_db('Attention! Oracle Error - ORA-' || v_ora_error || ' obtained. XA Process failed!');
    raise v_xa_exception;
  else dbms_output.put_line(a => 'XA Process ID 3322 started');
  end if;

end;
'''

req_start_continue = '''
declare
  v_my_transaction  pls_integer;
  v_xa_xid     dbms_xa_xid := dbms_xa_xid(3322);
  v_xa_exception exception;
  v_ora_error pls_integer;
begin

  v_my_transaction  := dbms_xa.xa_start(
                        xid => v_xa_xid,
                        flag =>  dbms_xa.tmresume);

--Check if XA transaction is OK
  if v_my_transaction <> dbms_xa.xa_ok then
    v_ora_error := dbms_xa.xa_getlastoer();
    rabus_utl.debug_db('Attention! Oracle Error - ORA-' || v_ora_error || ' obtained. XA Process failed!');
    raise v_xa_exception;
  else dbms_output.put_line(a => 'XA Process ID 3322 started');
  end if;

end;
'''

req_end = '''
declare
  v_my_transaction  pls_integer;
  v_xa_xid     dbms_xa_xid := dbms_xa_xid(3322);
  v_xa_exception exception;
  v_ora_error pls_integer;
begin

  v_my_transaction  := dbms_xa.xa_end(
                        xid => v_xa_xid,
                        flag =>  dbms_xa.tmsuspend);

 if v_my_transaction <> dbms_xa.xa_ok then
    v_ora_error := dbms_xa.xa_getlastoer();
   rabus_utl.debug_db('Attention! Oracle Error - ORA-' || v_ora_error || ' obtained. XA Process failed!');
    raise v_xa_exception;
   else dbms_output.put_line(a => 'XA Process ID 3322 is working!');
  end if;
end;

'''

req_end_rollback = '''
declare
  v_my_transaction  pls_integer;
  v_xa_xid     dbms_xa_xid := dbms_xa_xid(3322);
  v_xa_exception exception;
  v_ora_error pls_integer;
begin

  v_my_transaction  := dbms_xa.xa_end(
                        xid => v_xa_xid,
                        flag =>  dbms_xa.tmsuspend);

 v_my_transaction := dbms_xa.xa_rollback(
                             xid => v_xa_xid);

 if v_my_transaction <> dbms_xa.xa_ok then
    v_ora_error := dbms_xa.xa_getlastoer();
   rabus_utl.debug_db('Attention! Oracle Error - ORA-' || v_ora_error || ' obtained. XA Process failed!');
    raise v_xa_exception;
   else dbms_output.put_line(a => 'XA Process ID 3322 is working!');
  end if;
end;

'''

con1 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test', purity=cx_Oracle.ATTR_PURITY_NEW)
cur = con1.cursor()
cur.execute(req_start)
cur.execute('''insert into gui_view (id, name, view_type, title) values (gui_view_s.nextVal, 'TEST_VIEW', 'grid', 'VIEW_TITLE') ''')

cur1 = con1.cursor()
cur1.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all1 = cur1.fetchall()
assert len(rows_all1) > 0, 'Not Exists!'

cur.execute(req_end)
con1.close()

con2 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test1', purity=cx_Oracle.ATTR_PURITY_SELF)
cur2 = con2.cursor()
cur2.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all = cur2.fetchall()
assert len(rows_all) == 0, 'Exist!'

con3 = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass:127.0.0.1:1521/XE:POOLED', cclass='test')
cur3 = con3.cursor()
cur3.execute(req_start_continue)
cur3.execute('''select id from gui_view where title = 'VIEW_TITLE' ''')
rows_all3 = cur3.fetchall()
cur3.execute(req_end_rollback)
con3.close()

assert len(rows_all3) > 0, 'Not Exists!'
```

It works. 
May be it will help to somebody.
If your have other ideas for task please write here.